# Dynamic User Id

Tags: wp-query, users, author

How do I get the user id of my users dynamically from a custom function? As in not just the id of the currently logged in user but all users depending on which user's profile that you're on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question says "logged out" - logged out users do not have a user ID. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I've updated the question, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_the_author_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/) which returns the requested data of the author of the current post. If you're on the author archive page (e.g. author.php) that will be the ID of the user whose profile you are on.

```
get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work as I'm trying to echo the id from a function on a custom functions page as I'm trying to access the information through ajax.